# Styling a Spinner on the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-styles

I'm busy styling the theme of my app (blue/black with orange edges). I succesfully managed the actionbar, but I'm having trouble with a spinner/dropdown in the actionbar. Can anyone please suggest what I have to do to make the text color inside the spinner orange as well. Not the actual spinner items, just the one displayed at the top, i.e. the selected item.

At the moment it looks like this:
[image]

And the style I'm using for the spinner looks like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- SQUASHBOT THEME -->
    <style name="SquashBotTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/SquashBotTheme.ActionBarTheme</item>

        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/SquashBotTheme.DropDownNavigation</item>

    </style>

        <!-- ACTIONBAR THEME -->
    <style name="SquashBotTheme.ActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_theme</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/SquashBotTheme.TitleText</item>
    </style>

   <!-- TITLE TEXT --> 
   <style name="SquashBotTheme.TitleText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/OrangeRed</item>
    </style>

   <!-- DROPDOWN ITEM -->
   <style name="SquashBotTheme.DropDownNavigation" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
        <item name = "android:textAppearance">@color/OrangeRed</item>
        <item name = "android:textColor">@color/OrangeRed</item>
       <item name = "android:popupBackground">@color/OrangeRed</item>
   </style>

</resources>
```

As you can see, I've allready tried with `textAppearance` and `textColor`. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one:

spinner_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/YourStyleIsHere"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:singleLine="true"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_dropdawn2"
android:ellipsize="end" />
```

dropdown_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/YourAnotherStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/phone_ripple"
android:padding="20dp"
android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Adapter

```
adapter = new YourAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_item, models);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdown_item);
```

Styles have parent @android:style/TextAppearance"

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! Just remember to add layout_height to the dropdown_item

Comment: Although, now I can't select an item in the dropdown? It populates correctly and looks very nice, but when I click on item nr2 for example, nothing seems to happen. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @CodeVader maybe you have to override getDropDownView in your adapter and add the same code as getView there.

`@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomeView(position, convertView);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomeView(position, convertView);
        }

        private View getCustomeView(int position, View convertView) {
            // your stuff is here
            return convertView;
        }`